# pytest-html: Get rid of ASCII in capture log, so it doesn't show details link, when using logging?

Tags: logging, pytest-html

How can you get rid of what looks to be ASCII, in the capture log within the show details link, when the report is generated?  ASCII seems to appear, when running from command line, but not using PyCharm(addopts = --html=./logs/report.html --self-contained-html).
Picture:
[Report showing ASCII](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwa9E.jpg)

Also, how can you get rid of the `testscript` name and line number?  This appears when running at command line, as well as PyCharm.
Picture:
[Report showing `testscript` name and line number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3gk3.jpg)

Testcase file:

```
import os
import sys
import pytest

import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def test_one():
    print('')
    print("(test_one)  TEST1")
    LOGGER.info("(test_two)  INFO1:")
    LOGGER.warning("(test_two)  WARNING1:")
    LOGGER.error("(test_two)  ERROR1:")
    LOGGER.critical("(test_two)  CRITICAL1:")

    apple = 'red'
    assert apple == 'red'


def test_two():
    print('')
    print("(test_two)  TEST2")
    LOGGER.info("(test_two)  INFO2:")
    LOGGER.warning("(test_two)  WARNING2:")
    LOGGER.error("(test_two)  ERROR2:")
    LOGGER.critical("(test_two)  CRITICAL2:")

    pear = 'green'
    assert pear == 'green'
```

Logging file:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = DEBUG
log_cli_format = %(message)s

log_file = logs/pytest.log
log_file_level = DEBUG
log_file_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)8s: %(message)s
log_file_date_format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

Log file output:

```
20200611090159     INFO: (test_two)  INFO1:
20200611090159  WARNING: (test_two)  WARNING1:
20200611090159    ERROR: (test_two)  ERROR1:
20200611090159 CRITICAL: (test_two)  CRITICAL1:
20200611090159     INFO: (test_two)  INFO2:
20200611090159  WARNING: (test_two)  WARNING2:
20200611090159    ERROR: (test_two)  ERROR2:
20200611090159 CRITICAL: (test_two)  CRITICAL2:
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer:  Don't use logging system to print messages within the show details link.  If you run it from the command line, ASCII characters appear.
Regardless of how you run it, the report displays the name of the test script and line number.